# Can adjectives be direct objects?

Tags: objects, direct-objects, object-complements

Is this sentence grammatical?

> You look weak

Because look is a transitive verb, it needs a direct object. So can *Weak* be a direct object here? Or could it be **look** is a noun here?

Comment: "Look" is _intransitive_ here, and can be interpreted in the same way as the verb _to appear._ The usage will be easier to understand if you parse the sentence as if it were: _You appear (to be) weak._ The verb _look_ is very "troublesome" in English!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Look** in this sentence is used as a [Linking verb](http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/linking_verbs_examples/63/). they link the subject of the sentence to a word or phrase in the predicate that renames or describes the subject.

- If the verb is a form of be (be, being, been, am, is, are, was, were), you have a linking verb.
- For other verbs, if you can replace the verb with a form of "be" and the sentence makes sense, you have a linking verb.

In **"You look good"**, if you replace *look* with "are" you have "You are good", then *look* is used as linking verb. It is a synonym of "seem"

Examples with explanation:

> John is nice. (Is links John to an adjective describing him.)
>
> Lauren was at the theater. (Was links Lauren to a phrase telling us where she is.)
>
> Tanner feels sick. (Feels links Tanner to an adjective describing him.)
>
> Mr. Peters is our teacher. (Is links Mr. Peters to a noun renaming him.)
>
> The flower looks beautiful.

Comment: @user178049 yes, *look* can be intransitive or a linking verb. For example in *if you look carefully you can see it*, it is *intransitive*. But I think anyway it is not *transitive* to need *direct object*.